# Google Cloud JAVA SDK alternative for gsutil parallel_composite_upload_threshold

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

Team,

Is there any Google Cloud JAVA SDK alternative for gsutil parallel_composite_upload_threshold option?

Regards,
Tanmay

Answer (score 1):

The Java SDK does not support parallel composite uploads.